# How to limit an input so only certain letters or numbers are used? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, limit

beginner python user! I'm writing a tip calculator that will add a tip to a given meal amount but I've ran into a problem. Here is the code I need help with.

```
bill_amt = True
while bill_amt:
    bill_amt = float(input('First, what was the price of your meal?(Please do not use signs such as "$"):'))
    if bill_amt <= 0: #or if bill_amt has letters or symbols
        print('Your meal wasn\'t $',bill_amt, '! Please try again.')
        bill_amt = True
    else:
        x = float(bill_amt)
        bill_amt = False
```

I would like to be able to add to `if bill_amt <= 0:` with a command that will also catch symbols(excluding periods .) and letters so that if you input a price of $54.65 or 56.ad then you will have to enter a proper input. Thanks, sorry if this is a duplicate! -Pottsy

Comment: `float` will simply throw an error if the number is not a number. just catch it.

Comment: At first I was going to suggest a regex, but with this simple a problem popovitsji’s answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work.

```
bill_amt = True
while bill_amt:
    try:
        bill_amt = float(input('First, what was the price of your meal?(Please do not use signs such as "$"):'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter just a number')
        continue
    if bill_amt <= 0: #or if bill_amt has letters or symbols
        print('Your meal wasn\'t $',bill_amt, '! Please try again.')
        bill_amt = True
    else:
        x = float(bill_amt)
        bill_amt = False
```

Comment: Ditch the `bill_amt = True/False` stuff and `x = float(bill_amt)` stuff as it's not needed anymore, but I wholeheartedly approve of letting `float()` do the testing for you.

Comment: also you should catch the error you are handling, not all of them.  In this case `ValueError`